# How to properly use Universal Class Loader?

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to use **Universal Class Loader** functionality from Phalcon into my project, however I can't get it working.

Here is how i've implemented into my app (using [`registerClasses`](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html#registering-classes)).

index.php:

```
//...
$loader->registerClasses(
    array(
        "Commons" => "library/classes/CommonsClass.php"
    )
);

$loader->register();
```

sampleController.php:

```
public function doAction()
{
    $cc = new Commons();
}
```

And when I execute the controller, it throws me this exception:

`Fatal error:  Class 'Commons' not found in C:\the\path\to\phalcon_app\app\controllers\SomeController.php on line 63`

The [Phalcon Documentation](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/loader.html#registering-classes) just say that you need to register a class and call it in your funcion. There is something I've missed?

Ps.: The library folder is not registered anywhere (don't know if its needed), and it is in the same path as controllers, views, etc (`/app/`).

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check your directory structure.

given:

```
mah_app/app/config/loader.php
mah_app/library/classes/Commons.php
```

I would expect this to work:

```
// loader.php
$loader->registerClasses(
    array(
        "Commons" => __DIR__ . "/../../library/classes/Commons.php"
    )
)->register();
// works with $loader->registerDirs() for sure
```

Also, I would also suggest using namespaces and/or matching file name with class name.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I commented out the namespace declaration inside the class and it worked. Version 2.0.3.